# python how to loop data for search from json.file

Tags: python-3.x

i have this app, and i want to search for emails and  addresses for companies for all names from test.json file :

```
from lxml import html
import lxml.html
import requests
import argparse
import re, urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import json
import time



datenow = datetime.datetime.now()
now = datenow.strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S)")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--file', help='file help', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

file1 = args.file

with open(file1) as data_file:
  data = json.load(data_file)


for b_city in data['sponsors']:
    city = (b_city['city'])

for sponsors in data['sponsors']:
    name = (sponsors['business_name'])

company_name = '+'.join(name.split())
t = '+'.join(city.split())
company_city = ''.join(('+', t))

site = urllib.request.urlopen("http://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=site%:tripadvisor.com+"+company_name + company_city)
print("http://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=site%:tripadvisor.com+"+company_name + company_city)
data = site.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

my_list = soup.find("div", {"id": "links"}).find_all("div", {'class': re.compile('.*web-result*.')})[0:1]



(result__snippet, result_url) = ([] for i in range(2))

for i in my_list:
         try:
               result__snippet.append(i.find("a", {"class": "result__snippet"}).get_text().strip("\n").strip())
         except:
               result__snippet.append(None)
         try:
               result_url.append(i.find("a", {"class": "result__url"}).get_text().strip("\n").strip())
         except:
               result_url.append(None)

         d = (", ".join(result_url))

         weblinks = {'data': {
                    'link': d
          }}
         print(weblinks)

         print('tripadvisor.com , Searching ......')
         print(' ')




         urllink = weblinks['data']['link']

         urlstring = format(str(urllink))

         dom = lxml.html.fromstring(requests.get('https://'+urlstring).content)

         result = [x for x in dom.xpath('//a/@href') if 'mailto' in x]
         result2 = dom.xpath('//div[@class="ui_columns is-multiline is-mobile"]//h1/text()')
         result3 = dom.xpath('//div[@class="is-hidden-mobile blEntry address  ui_link"]//span[@class="street-address"]/text()')
         result4 = dom.xpath('//div[@class="is-hidden-mobile blEntry address  ui_link"]//span[@class="locality"]/text()')

         n = (", ".join(result2))
         b = (", ".join(result3))
         x = (", ".join(result4))
         s = ''.join((b, ', '))
         f = format(str(result))
         g = f[9:-12]

         final = {'data': {
              'source': 'tripadvisor.com',
               'name': n,
               'address': s + x,
               'email': g,
               'time': now
         }}

         no_email = {'data': {
               'name': n,
               'address': s + x,
               'email': 'Not Available'
         }}

         if(not final['data']['email']):

             dom = lxml.html.fromstring(requests.get('https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=' + company_name + '&geo_location_terms=' + t).content)
             result = dom.xpath('//div[@class="info"]//h2[@class="n"]/a[@class="business-name"]/@href')[0:1]
             result_string = (" ".join(result))
             weblinks1 = {'data': {
                'link': result_string
             }}

             print('tripadvisor.com: Email Not Available')
             print(' ')
             print(' ')
             print('yellowpages.com, Searching ........')
             print(' ')

             urllink1 = weblinks1['data']['link']

             urlstring1 = format(str(urllink1))

             dom = lxml.html.fromstring(requests.get('https://yellowpages.com' + urlstring1).content)

             result = dom.xpath('//*[@id="main-header"]/div[@class="business-card-footer"]/a[@class="email-business"]/@href')
             result2 = dom.xpath('//*[@id="main-header"]/article/div[@class="sales-info"]/h1/text()')
             result3 = dom.xpath('//*[@id="main-header"]/article/section[@class="primary-info"]/div[@class="contact"]/h2/text()')

             n = (", ".join(result2))
             b = (", ".join(result3))
             s = ''.join((b, ', '))
             f = (", ".join(result))



             final1 = {'data': {
               'email': f,
             }}

             if (not final1['data']['email']):
                print('yellowpages.com: Email Not Available')

             else:

                 g = f.split(":")[1]

                 final2 = {'data': {
                    'source': 'yellowpages.com',
                    'name': n,
                    'address': s,
                    'email': g,
                    'time': now
                 }}1)
             f = open('results_'+file1, 'a')
             print(final1, file=f)1)
             f = open('results_'+file1, 'a')
             print(final1, file=f)
```

and want to create loop for searching data from file test.json:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "msg": "Sponsors list ",
    "sponsors": [
        {
            "id": 831,
            "location": "90001",
            "city": "rapid city",
            "business_name": "The Grilled Cheese Truck",
            "latitude": "33.97908",
            "longitude": "-118.25009",
            "phone": "+18183451875",
            "address": "",
            "email": null,
            "created_at": "2019-09-16 11:59:28",
            "updated_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 832,
            "location": "90001",
            "city": "Huntington Park",
            "business_name": "Rays Texas BBQ",
            "latitude": "33.986598",
            "longitude": "-118.229803",
            "phone": "",
            "address": "6038 Santa Fe Ave",
            "email": null,
            "created_at": "2019-09-16 11:59:28",
            "updated_at": null
        },
        {
        "id": 890,
        "location": "90003",
        "city": "Los Angeles",
        "business_name": "Birrieria Jalisco",
        "latitude": "33.96956",
        "longitude": "-118.24735",
        "phone": "+13235839322",
        "address": "7714 Compton Ave",
        "email": null,
        "created_at": "2019-09-16 11:59:28",
        "updated_at": null
    }
    ]
}
```

but is searching only for last one from the list in the file atm
how to put on the loop so will search for all names and cities from this file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

that works :

```
for b_city in data['sponsors']:
    city = (b_city['city'])
    name = (sponsors['business_name'])
```

instead of:

```
for b_city in data['sponsors']:
    city = (b_city['city'])

for sponsors in data['sponsors']:
    name = (sponsors['business_name'])
```